# MySQL select one column with corresponding other column specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID      flag  
1       true
1       false
1       false
2       true
2       true
2       true
3       false
4       true
```

I need ID's `2` and `4` because they only have `true` flags. ID `1` and `3` will be rejected because they have one or more `false` flags.

Comment: Please post table structure with data so we can help you batter.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? Are you trying to select the rows that contain a value of `sequ` that only maps to true?

Comment: Yes! Jacob. I need Id which has only true flag.

Comment: The link Strawberry gave you describes some things that you can use to improve your post.

Comment: @MatBailie And you're perfectly entitled to it. I disagree. This is the thin end of the wedge.

Comment: @MatBailie What is a support site? Stack Overflow? No, it’s not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  MIN(flag) = true
```

Assuming your flag is a boolean datatype, the `MIN(flag)` will tell you if there are any `false` values in there.

Compared to `NOT IN()` and `NOT EXISTS()` this has the advantage of only scanning the table once and should be less expensive *(faster)*.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select distinct ID from table_name where ID not in (select distinct ID from table_name 
 where flag ='false');
```

Replace table_name with your table .

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select * from id;
+------+------+
| id   | flag |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    0 |
|    1 |    0 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    0 |
|    4 |    1 |
+------+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id,flag from id id1 where not exists (select id from id id2 where id2.flag=false and id1.id=id2.id);
+------+------+
| id   | flag |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    4 |    1 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that the OP would want all three copies of `id=2`, though they admittedly don't make it very clear.